# SSL client certificate protected URL from oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, authentication, stored-procedures, https

Is it possible to access an SSL client certificate protected URL from an oracle stored procedure somehow? With UTL_HTTP or with UTL_DBWS? With a Java stored procedure perhaps?
A code example would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example [here](http://eternal-donut.blogspot.com/2008/07/tip-5-using-utlhttp-and-ssl.html)

Comment: Hi Gary, that sample does not use client certificates.